# Modifying Primary Index of a table in Teradata

Tags: sql, database, indexing, teradata, alter

I am new to Teradata.
I have a table with around 45k records with a particular Primary index.
I want to change the primary index of this table.
Can somebody help pls?

Below is my current primary index.

```
PRIMARY INDEX IDX_NON_RTL_SALES_WIDE_01 ( col1 ,Col2 ,Col3 );
```

I want to remove col3 and add few other columns to it.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot alter a PI in teradata unless the table is empty.

You will need to copy the data out to another table, volatile or permanent.

Then you can alter your index:

```
alter table <TableName> modify primary index Index_Name(col1, col2, ...);
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, what if the table contains an identity column as a Primary Index? We cannot really recreate the table because it would generate new values for the Identity column which would not match with the current ones. Any idea how to change the UPI/PI on a table with identity column? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in general you should not change the PI on Teradata. I would suggest to create a new table w/ new PI and drop the old one.

```
CREATE TABLE BLA_new
  as BLA_old
  with data
PRIMARY INDEX ( <<new PI -columns>>);
DROP TABLE BLA_old;
```